# MySQL importing CSV files really slow

Tags: 18.04, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, csv

I am trying to import CSV files into a table, but it has been very slow. I have about 1000 files with a file size of 40 MB each. Whenever I try to import it, I can see with for example MySQL workbench that it is inserting in a rate of about 30 - 60 rows per second. It will take ages before al my files are processed. How can I speed this up? I have already modified the mysql.cnf file to the following config, which unfortunately does not speed it up:

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 48
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 48
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
max_connections = 1000
max_allowed_packet = 128M
#key_buffer = 1000M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024M
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
key_buffer_size = 4000M
```

It does say that 12G is configured in InnoDB according to PHPMyAdmin, so I can safely confirm that the config at least works.

Specs in case needed:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
CPU: 6 cores, 12 threads @ 4.5 GHz
RAM: 32 GB DDR4 @ 3.2 GHz
SSD: 1 TB NVME @ 3.5 GB/s Read & 3.3 GB/s Write
```

Comment: How do you do the inserts? One by one? Does the table have any indexes?

Comment: The inserts go one by one (Using Jetbrains Datagrip for it as phpmyadmin is very slow), and the table does not have any index to my knowledge

Answer (score 6):

You should have a look at the [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) function of MySQL, or the [`mysqlimport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) tool.

Those two functions are reportedly 20-30 times faster than `insert`'ing one by one, which would bring you up to at least 500-1000 rows a second.

As you don't provide any information about your data format, it's hard to give a detailed use instruction for `mysqlimport`, which seems to be the most applicable tool in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the file encoding was different between each file. Some files had UTF-8 encoding, some had ISO 8859-1 (Latin1) encoding, which caused a lot of programs to take ages to import due to (I think) converting it into another encoding. A 40 MB file now only takes about 6 seconds to import instead of 48 minutes.. Thanks @vidarlo for the suggestion of mysqlimport, which is certainly an improvement, but overall the time improvement is good enough for me!

Comment: Mark, Congratulations on your 6 second import time. Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile and we have Utility Scripts available to improve performance. I am looking forward to your contact.